# Alignment of equation in word

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I have this equation:
[image]

And I want to align the betas on the right, and the argument(QED,ED,QD) on the left. Currently I use brackets only.

Any clue on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a way in Word 2007; later versions should work similarly.  This is for the new-style equation editor, which I believe is what you're using since your screenshot is in the Cambria Math font.

1. in your equation, after the equals sign, insert left bracket from "Cases and Stacks":

[image: step 1]

2. Put the cursor just right of the two placeholder boxes:

[image: step 2]

3. Hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> twice to replace the two boxes with a single box:

[image: step 3]

4. Insert a matrix with three rows and two columns:

[image: step 4]

The result will be:

[image: result of step 4]

5. Fill in the contents of your matrix:

[image: step 5]

6. Right-click the left column, select Column Alignment, and pick Left:

[image: step 6]

7. Right-click the right column, select Column Alignment, and pick Right:

[image: step 7]

The final result:

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to set column alignment using shortcuts rather than the GUI, or a way to set a default column alignment?